How to assign specific value to one cell depending on the value of another
I am trying to organise a column of data based on the values of the adjoining column.
I have a list of values for some properties, and depending on these values, the properties must be assigned a rating from A to F.
For example, if the value in D1 is 39, then the value in E1 should show A.
If the value in D1 is less than 39, E1 should be B, and if the value in D1 is less than 32, E1 needs to show C etc.
I have tried conditional formatting, but can only format the entire box, there is no way I can find to just enter a letter.
I have also tried a formula like =IF (D1 <39 AND >36, A, <36 AND >32, B, <32, C) but this didn't work either.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
